# xpath address where td not containing span

Tags: javascript, python, html, xpath, web-scraping

I want the xpath of only td that don't have span with class "nop", in below example the first, second and fifth td:

```
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td><span class="nowrp"></td>
  <td><span class="nowrp"></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
```

I tried this but didn't worked:

```
//td[not(contains(@class, 'nowrp'))]
```

and this didn't worked as well:

```
//td[not(contains(span, (@class, 'nowrp')))]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your xml is invalid. But assuming you fix it like so:

```
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td><span class="nowrp">3</span></td>
  <td><span class="nowrp">4</span></td>
  <td>5</td>
</tr>
```

this xpath expression

```
//td[not(contains(./span/@class, 'nowrp'))]
```

should output:

```
 1
 2
 5
```